# iOS Sorting by Parse relation size

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have some User objects on my Parse backend with a relation with "Comment" objects. I want to query and sort by the users with the highest number of objects in the previous relation, however I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to sort by relation size but you could have a number variable to keep track of the comments, and increment it whenever a comment is created.

Answer (score 0):

I assume after parsing your response you are left with an array of objects with a property `comments` which is again an array of objects, something like this:

```
// NSLog(@"%@", users);

(
    {
        comments = (
            {
                date = "2016-01-13T02:04:52+00:00";
                content = "nice comment, bro";
            }
        );
        userName = "louise.lausebär";
    }
)
```

Sorting that by count of comments is super simple with `NSSortDescriptor` and [KVO Collection Operators](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"comments.@count" ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

Comment: I want to avoid pulling all the events and  then sorting them by the comment amount as I'm probably going to have a large number of objects on the backend. Is there anyway to calculate the size of a relation and only query certain objects whose relation are that size?